# How can I prevent/divert rain water from dripping on a flat flashing?

Tags: roof, drainage, sound-proofing, rain

I'm helping maintain a set of townhome units and the homeowners are reporting an annoying drip sound just outside their bedroom when it lightly rains (which is quite often). Apparently the sound is loud enough and at just the right frequency that it is quite audible with the windows closed.

I managed to recreate the problem with a hose and found that when water trickles down the rooftop patio railing, it drips onto a flashing that rests flat on top of a brick finish (see picture below).

What is the ideal way to fix this? And what is a quick fix we could do to fix this in the short-term?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a set of gargoyles:

> Definition and Origin of Gargoyles and Grotesques
>   Gargoyles came into gothic architecture in the early 13th century and are defined as "a waterspout, projecting from an upper part of a building or a roof gutter to throw water clear of walls or foundations." The origins of the word 'gargoyle' are derived from the old French word 'gargouille' meaning throat.

A simple length of wire, extending down and outward from the point where the drop originates, should move the water clear of the brick and flashing.  A few inches should be enough.

More ornate structures

[image]

are optional